# Jqplot - Replot is not a function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jqplot

I am loading a jqplot graph into a initially hidden bootstrap tab.
I am aware that when doing this, you have to reload the graph to be able to actually see it.

I am doing the following code:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target).attr("href") // activated tab

    $(target).children(".jqplot-target").each(function() {
        var graphId = eval(this.id);

        graphId.replot();
    });
});
```

I have executed similar code before and had no issue but for some reason in this case i get the following error:

TypeError: graphId.replot is not a function

Thanks in advance.